# How do I select the line in bash terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

Is it possible to select part of a string in the bash terminal and delete it at once, rather than navigating to a point in the command and backspacing it all??

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.

If you are at the interactive command line:

- `ctrl-u`: Deletes everything to the left of your cursor
- `ctrl-k`: Deletes everything to the right of your cursor

Answer (score 2):

I'm using emacs bindings and my favourite command line shortcuts, which were not included in the previously linked tutorial, are the following:

```
^W     - delete last word
meta-b - move cursor back one word
^R     - find a previously used command
!$     - last attribute of the last command
!!     - last command
```

You can also manipulate the history with regexps, although that could quickly get quite messy. See "man zshexpn" for reference, mostly the same regexp syntax works for bash also.

Example:

1) If you execute the following command:

> ```
>  echo first second third fourth fifth
> ```

2) Then you could execute the same command and remove "first" by:

> ```
>  !!:s/first//
> ```

If this was not what you were after, please clarify on your question! :)

Comment: It does not matter, you may still use emacs key bindings in your shell. I don't use emacs either but I love its bindings in zsh shell.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/). Alternatively, `set -o vi` to have vim-like key bindings.

Note that the list given in the link is not full. You might read `man bash` for a good reference. Usually, ALT-x might be replaced by ESC, x if you run bash inside a terminal that uses Alt-letter shortcuts for windowing system.